# Sqlmetal failing to generate dbml file for SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 db

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce, sqlmetal

I can't seem to generate a dbml file using Sqlmetal for a simple SSCE 3.5 db.

I am using the VS command prompt, am sitting in the VS project directory that contains the db, and then enter the following Sqlmetal command at the prompt :

**sqlmetal /dbml:fom.dbml fom.sdf**

sqlmetal returns the following error :

**Error : Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification st
arting at index 0.**

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here ?

*[Note that I am running Windows 7 64. I have tried all three VS command prompts.. all result in same error].*

Comment: Do you have both the x86 and x64 SQL Server Compact runtime MSIs installed?

Comment: I have now solved this particular error...SQLMetal did not seem to like directory names with spaces in them After moving db to a simple directory (eg. c:\temp) I was able to generate a dbml. However, now I have a new issue. The new dbml appears in visual studio 2010 ok, ie. model can be displayed. However, context classes are not generated - ie. there is no code behind the dbml at all it seems.

Comment: Also, yes, I have both SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU & SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 x64 ENU installed.

Comment: OK, so your question did not reveal that your were using a path with spaces.. suggest you update the question. Why not simply generated the .cs files instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved this particular error...SQLMetal did not seem to like directory names with spaces in them After moving db to a simple directory *without* any spaces in directory name (eg. c:\temp\mydb.sdf) I was able to generate a dbml successfully.